# Init or main function in Julia

Tags: program-entry-point, julia

I've read that global variables have a sensible impact on performance.

In order to avoid them I've put everything inside a **init** function, as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923726/declaring-main-function-entry-point-in-julia).

Simple example, integer.jl:

```
function __init__()
    n = 0
    while n < 2
        try
            print("Insert an integer bigger than 1: ")
            n = parse(Int8,readline(STDIN))
        catch Error
            println("Error!")
        end
    end

    println(n)
end
```

When I run `julia integer.jl` from the command line, nothing happens. `function main()` doesn't work either.

What should I do to make it work?

(Also, can you correct any errors, non efficient code or non idiomatic syntax?)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The name `__init__` is reserved as a name for a function in a module that is automatically run when the module is loaded, so unless that's what you're defining, don't use that name. You can call this function `main` (which has no special meaning) and then just call it like so:

```
function main()
    # do stuff
end

main()
```

Comment: Does Julia have any guard like `if __name__ == '__main__':` in Python?
This is sometimes useful for libraries that also have some kind of standalone debug/testing mode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462557/within-a-julia-script-can-you-tell-whether-the-script-has-been-imported-or-exec but in short, I'm not sure why you'd need to be able to run the same file as a script or as something that defines a module.